# How do I add a link to a table row in a custom module?

Tags: 8

I am making a sortable table in a custom module. If I put the whole link as part of the row information, the URL does not come out right.

I tried the following code.

```
  array(
    'data'=>array(
      '#title' => $entry['name'],
      '#type' => 'link',
      '#url' => $entry['link_url'],
    )
  )
```

I also tried what suggested on https://www.drupal.org/node/745272,  which describes how to do it for Drupal 7.

I also tried this code.

```
 $rows[] = array(
   array(
     'data' => array(
       'name' => new FormattableMarkup('<a href=":link">@name</a>', [':link' => $entry['link_url'], '@name' => $entry['name']])
     )
   )
 );
```

Neither displays anything.

How do I achieve this for Drupal 8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This worked for me

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;  
  $rows[] = array(

      array('data' => new FormattableMarkup('<a href=":link">@name</a>', 
        [':link' => $entry['link_url'], 
        '@name' => $entry['name']])
      ),
```

Comment: You really should be using the Url and/or Link class rather than coding your own markup.

Answer (score 2):

according to the [link docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Link.php/class/Link/8.2.x) you should try this Structure, you need to create the route on your custom module.

```php
$rows[] = [
  'data' => [
    'label' => [
      'data' => [
        'link' => [
          '#type' => 'link',
          '#title' => 'link text',
          '#url' => Url::fromRoute('custom_module.route'),
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the core [Url class](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x). Include it in your custom class:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
```

And then use something like this for your table data link:

```
'#url' => Url::fromUri($entry['link_url']),
```

There are a number of options for fromUrl() you may want to look at, and depending on the nature of your link_url values, there are other Url class methods that may be more appropriate.

Comment: that didnt help since the problem was i was trying to include the url and the name in the same row in a table.  the answer above did work

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick for me:

```
use Drupal\Core\Url;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Render\Markup;

$url = Url::fromRoute('entity.node.edit_form', array('node' => NID));
$project_link = Link::fromTextAndUrl(t('Open Project'), $url);
$project_link = $project_link->toRenderable()->toString();

$header = [
  'title' => t('title'),
  'data' => Markup::create($project_link)
];
```